# Import Contacts Issue After Joomla 4.4.0 Upgrade - Stuck at 'Running Queue

Tags: contacts, joomla, import, data-import

I am using CiviCRM 5.64.2. A few days ago, I upgraded Joomla from version 4.3.0 to 4.4.0. Normally, I used to import a list of user data that I receive daily with a CSV file separated by semicolons using the 'Import Contacts' option. I did this for two days after the Joomla update. Today, I am unable to import with both the old and newly created CSV files. The process hangs at the screen as seen in the screenshot.

[image]

When I click the Retry button, nothing changes. When I click the Skip button, it terminates the process and does not import any data.

The data source, Mapping Steps, and Preview steps all look normal. However, when I click 'Import,' there is no progress in the 'Running Queue' screen. Previously, using this method, I could import 400-500 records at once, but now it won't import even a single one. I have also tried this on a different system with the same Joomla and CiviCRM versions, and the issue persists. I request your support to find a solution to this problem.

It could be related to the CiviCRM update, but there is an issue with the update. Detailed information about this problem can be found at [Upgraded to Joomla 4, now unable to upgrade CiviCRM](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/upgraded-to-joomla-4-now-unable-to-upgrade-civicrm).

Information about the errors in the Error.Log file is also available at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/-/issues/51#note_92343.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the steps I followed to resolve this issue. These steps worked for me, and if there's no risk for you, you can try them as well.

**Important**: Before starting these procedures, be sure to take a complete backup. I perform backups via SSH using the command: `` for i in `cat /etc/trueuserowners | awk ' { print $1 } ' | tr -d :` ;  do /scripts/pkgacct $i ; done `` When I need to restore, I enter the `/home` directory and use the command: `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/restorepkg --skipaccount cpmove-joomla.tar.gz` for restoration.

1. First, download the latest CiviCRM version for Joomla, extract the
   ZIP file, and place it in the `/tmp/` directory.
2. Backup the files `/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php`
   and `/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php`
   to your computer.
3. Rename the com_civicrm folder in the `/components/` and
   `/administrator/components/` directories to `com_civicrm2` or
   any other name of your choice.
4. Access **Joomla** > **System** > **Extensions** > **Manage
   Extensions** and disable all extensions related to CiviCRM (do not
   uninstall, just disable).
5. Start the update from **Joomla** > **System** > **Extensions** >
   **Install from Folder** using the path `/home/joomlaa/public_html/tmp/com_civicrm`. After installation,
   you will receive an error message; please disregard it.
6. Restore the backup copies of
   `/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php` and
   `/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php` to
   their respective locations.
7. Delete everything under the `/media/civicrm/templates_c` path.
8. Download the latest version of localization files and place them
   under `/administrator/components/com_civicrm`.
9. Access **Joomla** > **System** > **Extensions** > **Manage
   Extensions** and re-enable all extensions related to CiviCRM
   (usually just CiviCRM).
10. Refresh the page where you received the error in Step 5 and start
    the database update. This time, the database update will proceed
    without any PHP errors, and the installation will be completed
    smoothly.

After these steps, I didn't experience any data loss or configuration changes.

If everything is successful, you can use SSH commands `rm -rf /home/joomla/public_html/components/com_civicrm2` and `rm -rf /home/joomla/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm2` to delete the folders you renamed for backup purposes.