# Common Issue with Quick Search Functionality After Upgrading Multiple CRMs

Tags: joomla, search, phone, quicksearch

I have recently upgraded multiple CRM instances to version 5.67.0 their respective latest versions, and I'm encountering a common issue with the Quick Search functionality in all of them. Before the upgrades, I could search for contacts by their phone numbers, and the search results would display the relevant contact's phone number and email address alongside their name. However, after the upgrades, when I perform a Quick Search using a phone number, the search results do not seem to be related to the input phone number at all. In fact, the results only display the contact's name, and these names are often incorrect.

Only the Phone option is active as a search option in quick search options. All other E-Mail, ID, External ID, etc. options are disabled.

[image]

This issue is affecting our ability to efficiently locate contacts in all of our CRM databases. I haven't made any changes to the CRM settings, so I believe this problem may be related to the recent upgrades to the respective CRM versions.

Could you please assist in resolving this common issue and provide guidance on how to restore the previous functionality of the Quick Search feature for phone numbers in multiple CRMs? Your support is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Fatih. are you able to compare what you are seeing with one of the 'demo' sites (assuming there is a Joomla demo site on latest)

Comment: Can you confirm that during your Civi upgrade you deleted all old files from the CiviCRM source code directory before replacing it with the new version?

Comment: In search preferences (customise data & screens) , there is a setting to include email.  Is this  set to 'Yes' ?  This got unset for one of my clients.

Comment: Hello @petednz-fuzion I couldn't make a comparison because there is a "U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR" error for J4 on cividemo.com. I think the issue might be related to my installation, as the same V4 version and the same CiviCRM version have the same problem on different sites with 5 different domain names.

Comment: Hello @Coleman I encountered an upgrade issue from CiviCRM 5.64.2 onwards. The J4 version kept throwing a continuous 500 error. Details of the installation steps I followed can be found at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/45810/6848. If the question is about deleting all CiviCRM files in FTP, yes, the installation was done after everything was deleted.

Comment: Hello @AndyClark the "Email Opt Out" option in the Settings - Search Preferences section is already set to "Yes." I haven't made any changes to these settings. What's even more interesting is that when I (Joomla superuser) perform a query with any number using quick search, results are displayed. However, when anyone else performs the same query, no results are shown.

Comment: Hi Fatih - re. anyone else getting no results, my first thought is that there must be a problem with permissions - have you checked that?

Comment: Hello Andy Clark, I noticed the issue first (as the superuser). I entered the View Settings section, saved without making any changes, and exited. Then I went to the Search Preferences section, again saved without making any changes, and exited. After that, I got results in quick search. When I received complaints from some colleagues on the team that they couldn't perform searches during the day, I checked their permissions. The permissions are as they should be.

Comment: By the way, I don't know if it helps or not, but after the update, the Relationships and Notes options came to the Profile (View Contact) field. When I checked from the view settings, the options were closed. I activated the option, saved, then deactivated and saved again, but they don't go away.

Comment: And does it all work on a non-joomla demo as expected?

Comment: The versions of the demo sites at https://civicrm.org/demo are outdated. I couldn't check them because they throw a U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR for Joomla. The same error exists in my own CiviCRM 5.67.0 with 5 different domain names. Additionally, despite being disabled in the View settings, the Notes and Relationships communication tabs that come with this update are visible in the View Contact section.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, thank you for engaging with this troublesome issue. The fact that it occurred for some users and not others was truly meaningful. Today, I requested the users experiencing the issue to log in using an Incognito Tab. I observed that there were no issues. Therefore, clearing the Browser History resolved the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same errors and I am running civicrm 5.67.0 with drupal 9.5.11. I did not realize we were supposed to delete the source files first before upgrading - all these years and I have not been doing that. I am expecting you mean to delete the civicrm module and then use composer to require the new module ? What about the Vendor directory - are we supposed to delete anything there too?

BTW- I tried incognito in the FireFox browser with the same result - If I ask for a phone number, I get all 1,042 individuals listed vs. a single individual.

Comment: This would be better as  a new Question - it is likely to be down voted as it does not seem to be an Answer